# Convergence of Proximal Gradient Descent

Tags: convergence-divergence, convex-analysis, gradient-descent, non-convex-optimization, proximal-operators

**1. Background of Proximal Gradient Descent**

I am studying and using Proximal Gradient Descent (PGD) to solve the following vector optimization problem:

$$
\hat{\mathbf{x}}=\underset{{\mathbf{x}}}{\arg\min}~f(\mathbf{x})+\lambda g(\mathbf{x}),
$$

where $\hat{\mathbf{x}}\in\mathbb{R}^N$ is the estimation of target signal $\bar{\mathbf{x}}$ I want, $f:\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow[0,+\infty)$ is a smooth and convex function (e.g. $\ell_2$-error), $g:\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow[0,+\infty)$ is a convex function (regularizer), and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^+$ is the regularization parameter.

From [[Lecture Note 1](http://people.csail.mit.edu/stefje/fall15/notes_lecture13.pdf)],[[Lecture Note 2](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eelghaoui/Teaching/EE227A/lecture18.pdf)] and [[Lecture Note 3](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Eryantibs/convexopt/lectures/prox-grad.pdf)], I may know that for a given initialization $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_0$, the PGD is convergent ($\hat{\mathbf{x}}_k\rightarrow \bar{\mathbf{x}}$), and the iterating step of which is as follows:

$$
\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{k+1}=\text{prox}_{\lambda g}(\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{k}-\rho_k\nabla f(\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{k})),
$$

where $\rho_k$ is the step size.

---

**2. Background of My Experiments**

(I do some experiments for the Compressed Sensing (CS) task based on LASSO criterion, which aims to linearly subsample a sparse signal and nonlinearly recover it.)

In my experiments, I discover that the trivial PGD method is able to find a good solution which can be close to $\bar{\mathbf{x}}$.

Then, I generalize the original optimization problem to a high-dimensional space:

$$
\hat{\mathbf{X}}=\underset{{\mathbf{X}}}{\arg\min}~F(\mathbf{X})+\lambda G(\mathbf{X}),
$$

and solve it using generalized PGD:

$$
\hat{\mathbf{X}}_{k+1}=\text{prox}_{\lambda G}(\hat{\mathbf{X}}_{k}-\rho_k\nabla F(\hat{\mathbf{X}}_{k})),
$$

where the iterations perform in an $(N+C)$-dimensional space, each $\hat{\mathbf{X}}_k\in\mathbb{R}^{N+C}$ is a generalized middle result in the feature space with a higher dimensionality $(N+C)$, and the generalized $F(\cdot)$ and $G(\cdot)$ take the same forms of the original $f(\cdot)$ and $g(\cdot)$ (the difference is that the generalized ones take $(N+C)$-dimensional inputs).

Here I project the initialization to an $(N+C)$-dimensional feature space $\hat{\mathbf{X}}_0=\mathbf{A}\hat{\mathbf{x}}_\text{init}\in\mathbb{R}^{N+C}$ ($\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{(N+C)\times N}$), and get the final estimation by a linear recoverer $\hat{\mathbf{x}}=\mathbf{B}\hat{\mathbf{X}}_K\in\mathbb{R}^{N}$ ($\mathbf{B}\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times(N+C)}$, $K$ is the total iteration number). And there is $\mathbf{BA}=\mathbf{I}_N$, *i.e.*, $\forall \mathbf{x}$, $\mathbf{BAx}=\mathbf{x}$.

After some fine-tunings and utilizations of deep learning for getting all the hyper-parameters and settings, I discover that the above generalization is possible to get a better result than the original one under the same setting of total iteration number $K$, the mean squared error is able to be further reduced.

However, the deep learned parameters of PGD or generalized PGD, from my pre-collected dataset, acts like black-box, so it is hard for me to interpret them.

(More distracting details are omitted.)

---

**3. My Question**

When $C=0$ and $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{I}_N$, with some trivial settings, the generalizetion degrades to the original framework.

$(3.1)$ I am confused by that why the generalization is able to get better results when $C>0$ with some proper settings?

$(3.2)$ Is there a way to show that the generalized PGD is able to converge (*e.g.*, $\mathbf{B}\hat{\mathbf{X}}_k\rightarrow \bar{\mathbf{x}}$) faster than the original one, under some assumptions? I guess that the high-dimensional PGD is able to be more powerful, at least in constant scale.

$(3.3)$ Is the observed phenomenon related to the "momentum" strategy?

---

**4. My Efforts**

After a long struggle and searching online, I can still not prove the superiority or the faster convergence of the generalized PGD, optimizing in a high-dimensional feature space.

I can even not find a correct point to start.

Is there a way to show or analyse this?

Could you please prove or disprove that the generalized PGD may be better than the original PGD?

---

**Update (2022-7-13):**

I am working on the application of mathematical induction. Specifically, $\forall k\in \mathbb{N}$, I want to prove or disprove the following inequality:

$$
\lVert \mathbf{BX}_k -\mathbf{x}^* \rVert^2_2 \le \lVert \mathbf{x}_k -\mathbf{x}^* \rVert^2_2.
$$

When $k=0$, there is $\mathbf{BX}_0=\mathbf{BAx}_0=\mathbf{x}_0$.

Then I suppose that the inequality holds when $0\le k\le t$, and am stuck by analyzing the case of $k=t+1$.

Is this a correct way? How to make some assumptions to solve it?

Comment: How are you defining $A$ and $B$ and extending $f$ and $g$ to $F$ and $G$? This part is nontrivial. In general, you cannot hope to improve the rate. Even if the minimizers of both problems are coherent in some sense (e.g., the projection of $X^\star$ is $x^\star$ or something), the convergence rate for both algorithms will be the same - except the constant in the higher dimensional algorithm will be worse.

Comment: Hi @j.kookalinski, thank you for your help! I want to know that if there exists a way to perform PGD in a high-dimensional space with **some proper settings** of $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$, $F(\cdot)$, $G(\cdot)$ and other hyper-parameters, to make the optimization process faster (or not slower, in constant, *i.e*, the generalized framework can at least converge as fast as the original one, *e.g.* $\lVert \mathbf{\hat{x}}_k-\mathbf{x}^* \rVert \ge \lVert \mathbf{B\hat{X}}_k-\mathbf{x}^* \rVert$)? Is it possible? And how can I prove this?

Comment: When $C=0$, $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{I}_N$, $F=f$ and $G=g$, the two frameworks should have the same performance. Intuitively, the generalized one could be more powerful than the original one, at least in constant. I do not know if there are some previous works w.r.t. the idea.

Comment: Hi @j.kookalinski, in my experiements, all the parameters are deeply learned based on neural network (NN). It benefits from a pre-collected large dataset and acts like a black box, so I can not directly interpret it and its learned parameters. I may only guess that the generalized framework could be more powerful in constant at least.

Comment: "Intuitively, the generalized one could be more powerful than the original one, at least in constant. " This is wrong - the best known convergence rates are already attained using accelerated algorithms like Nesterov's method or triple momentum, etc. What you are describing seems to be completely unrelated.

Comment: Hi @j.kookalinski, thanks for pointing these out! I was not sure if the high-dimensional PGD can be better (faster) in **constant** scale (I guess that this may be possible). After a long struggle, now I may tend to believe that this could actually not be achieved (*i.e.*, the generalized PGD may not be faster). Is there a way to analyse them?